# How to change field type using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes

I can change the field type (e.g. string to integer) via:

- Processing > Refactor fields

How can I do it purely using PyQGIS via a script or the Python Console (I do not want to call the algorithm itself)?

I checked the code of the [Refactor fields algorithm](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d5617b8025e0b1ea09a4f83ca464b7306cad535b/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/FieldsMapper.py) but not sure what lines to use. I also checked [QgsField](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Field/QgsField.html#qgis.core.QgsField.setType) which has the `setType()` function but that doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have tried:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):
    fields = layer.fields()
    fields[7].setType(QVariant.Int)
    fields[7].setTypeName('Int')
    layer.updateFields()
```

Comment: That code is for a field mapper and not for a field, the type can be changed because the output doesn't exist yet. Are you sure your data supports changing a fields' type? JSON might but shapefile, PostGIS etc will not be able to change a field type for an existing field, the underlying database will not allow it.